# (dart) I want two different onclick function to trigger depending if the radio button is checked or not upon clicking. How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, html, dart

I'm working on a game project where the user has to click the radio button that is checked randomly.

If he clicks the radio button that is checked, another one is randomly generated and the one he just clicked is unchecked.

If he clicks a radio button that is unchecked, he loses the game.

So both clicking even trigger a different function.

Right now I have :

```
var Buttons = querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

Buttons.onClick.listen(
  (event) => hithead(id));
```

which makes the same function happen on all radio clicks regardless if checked or not. How do I make it so that it uses one only if the radio clicked is checked and uses the other if the radio clicked was unchecked ?

*edit*

I've tried using something like this :

```
Buttons.onClick.listen(
 if(Buttons.checked == true){
    (event) => function1();
  }
  else{
    function2();
  }
```

But it doesnt work and gives me a couple errors

*EDIT2*

```
Buttons.onClick.listen((event) {
if (event.target.id == currentRadioId) {
  function1();
  currentRadioId = event.target.id;
}
else {
  function2();
  currentRadioId = event.target.id;
}
});
```

*EDIT3*

```
var Buttons= querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
String currentRadioId = "";

Buttons.onClick.listen(clickradio);

clickradio(MouseEvent event) {
InputElement checkradio = event.target;
var checked = checkradio.checked;
if (checked){
function1();
} else {
function2();
}
}
```

Comment: Use the `event` object to determine if it is checked or not! Then a simple `if else` statement to control your flow!

Comment: I edited the thread to show you my visualization of your comment, did you meant something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using an arrow function like you do, nor do I use a radio button, but my sample code may give you a clue - you could retrieve the `checked` property from `event` object (as well as other properties upon your requirement):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox">
<div></div>
```

**DART**

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector('input')
      ..onClick.listen(clickFun);
}

void clickFun(MouseEvent event) {
  // please note here how I get the checked property
  InputElement checkbox = event.target;
  var checked = checkbox.checked;
  if (checked) {
    writeLog('checked');
  } else {
    writeLog('unchecked');
  }
}

void writeLog(log) {
  querySelector('div').text = log;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

As of OP's comment, I think he misunderstood radio button's use case. Here's the explanation:

**Radio button** (`<input type="radio"`>) is usually use for a group of mutually exclusive options, and you are restricted to choose **only one** among them. So, whichever radio button you clicked, its checking state is always **checked**, indicates you chose that option.

In following demo, you will never see an alert saying `false`, all you get is `true`:

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="r" value="1" onclick="alert(this.checked)"> 1</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="r" value="2" onclick="alert(this.checked)"> 2</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="r" value="3" onclick="alert(this.checked)"> 3</label>
```

On the other hand, in my previous answer I used **Checkbox** (`<input type="checkbox"`>). This is used for **toggling** on/off state of a single option (opposite to one of mutually exclusive options). Try this demo and you will see why I suggest checkbox over radio button.

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c" onclick="alert(this.checked)"> checkbox</label>
```

---

However, if you still want the **look** of a radio button, you could override its appearance:

```css
input {
  -webkit-appearance: radio;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> This is a checkbox, I swear!</label>
```

Comment: I've tried this approached except I replaced your write log function by hithead() (if checked) and stopgame() (if unchecked) but it seems to do the hithead() function regardless if I click a radio that is check or unchecked.

See edit3 for my interpretation of your approach.

Answer (score 0):

When the click event fires for your radio button, its state will necessarily be checked.  You could keep track of the `id` of the currently selected radio button and compare that against the `id` of the one for which the click event fired.  If it's not the same, then the user clicked an unchecked radio

Declaring a string under your original selector:

```
var elemDmz = querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
String currentRadioId = '';
```

You could do something like:

```
elemDmz.onClick.listen((event) {
  if (event.target.id == currentRadioId) {
    print('checked radio clicked');
    currentRadioId = event.target.id;
  } else {
    print('unchecked radio clicked');
    currentRadioId = event.target.id;
  }
});
```

Comment: I updated the main comment with the function I added under edit2. It seems to partially work but it gives me the stopgame() function regardless if I click a checked or unchecked radio.